# How to prevent page refresh on button click in React Native function

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the below React Native function we want to stop random array from initializing on every button click. Currently when we press the button the counter gets incremented as well as the array get initialized again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

const Game1 = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  handlePress = () => {
      // if (selectedNoArry == 0) {
      setCount(count + 1);
      // selectedNoArry.concat(index);
      // console.log(selectedNoArry);
      // }
      //return false;
  };

  const randomNoArry = Array.from(
    {length: props.randomnno},
    x => 1 + Math.floor(10 * Math.random()),
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{marginTop: 40}}>
        you hit {count}!
      </Text>
      <Text style={{marginTop: 40}}>
       this is randomn {randomNoArry}!
      </Text>
      <Button style={{marginTop: '40'}}
         onPress={() => handlePress()}
         title="click Me"
      
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Game = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Game1 randomnno="6" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

To test please copy paste above code [here](https://snack.expo.io/XgcQecANt)

Comment: You can use the [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook to memoize the `randomNoArry` variable. `const randomNoArry = useMemo(() => Array.from({ length: props.randomnno }, (x) => 1 + Math.floor(10 * Math.random())),[props.randomnno]);`

Comment: useMemo works well, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the data in `useRef()` or `useState()` to prevent it from regenerated automatically.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

const genRanArr = (length) =>
  Array.from({ length: length }, (x) => 1 + Math.floor(10 * Math.random()));

const Game1 = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [randomArray, setRandomArray] = useState(genRanArr(props.name));

  const handlePress = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>you hit {count}!</Text>
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>this a randomn {randomArray}!</Text>
      <Button
        style={{ marginTop: "40" }}
        onPress={() => handlePress()}
        title="click Me"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const Game = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Game1 name="6" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well. I didn't know that component re-renders when using state.